# bonding of bond interface in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, bonding

Is it possible to bonding of bond interface?

I have two NIC bonded as **bond0** (balance mode) and two other NIC bonded as **bond1** (balance mode). I want to create bond2 (active back-up mode) by using bond0 and bond1.

Additional Information : I'm using Ububntu 13.04

Comment: Doing this would be asking for trouble. What are you trying to achieve? Balanced bond have a fail-over ability. Describe your network environment more.

Comment: Thanks, actually I want to create active back-up bonding from two different type balanced bond, first is (10GB+10GB) and second is(1GB+1GB).

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot bond multiple bonds.